# How to find 2nd td in html using xpath

Tags: html, xpath, html-table

I have 2 occourances of same td in 2 different tables.

I am able to get the value 'Yes' for the 1st one using this:

```
//h:td[1][*[contains(.,'Loudspeaker')]]/../h:td[last()]/text()
```

but not getting the value 'Voice 75dB / Noise 66dB / Ring 75dB' for the 2nd one.
I tried:

```
//h:td[2][*[contains(.,'Loudspeaker')]]/../h:td[last()]/text()
```

I am very new to html and xpath so please bear with me.

portion of my html:

```
</table><table cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<th rowspan="3" scope="row">Sound</th>
<td class="ttl"><a href="glossary.php3?term=call-alerts">Alert types</a></td>
<td class="nfo">Vibration; MP3, WAV ringtones</td>
    </tr>

<tr>
<td class="ttl"><a href="glossary.php3?term=loudspeaker">Loudspeaker</a> </td>
<td class="nfo">Yes</td>
</tr>
```

.
.

```
<table cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<th rowspan="5" scope="row">Tests</th>
<td class="ttl"><a href="xyz.php">Display</a></td>
<td class="nfo">
<a class="noUnd" href="http://xyz.php">Contrast ratio: Infinite (nominal) / 3.419:1     (sunlight)</a></td>
</tr><tr>

<td class="ttl"><a href="xyz.php">Loudspeaker</a></td>
<td class="nfo">
<a class="noUnd" href="http://xyz.php">Voice 75dB / Noise 66dB / Ring 75dB</a></td>
</tr><tr>
```

..

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you please post the whole thing? at least the common parent block containing both td's so that we don't have to recreate a sample html.

Comment: The html page is some 800 lines. however, you can get the html from this website page. Hope this will suffice (http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s_duos_s7562-4883.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference between these two snippets is that in the second one your text is nested within an `a` element. So it has to be

```
//h:td[2][*[contains(.,'Loudspeaker')]]/../h:td[last()]/h:a/text()
```

(I guess you have a namespace definition for `h` as you use it in your XPath.

Comment: dirkk- I tried this and it worked. (//h:td[1][*[contains(.,'Loudspeaker')]]/../h:td[last()]/h:a/text()). Just changed 2 to 1 in your code. but I did not understand how it worked?

Comment: This depends on your data and you did not showed this, so I simply used 2 as you did in your query. The difference is that `td[1]` will select the first `td` element whereas `td[2]` selects the second one. It is a condition based on the position of the node element as XML nodes are ordered.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is:

`//h:td[2]` find each second td  in the whole document (main issue here, because there is no second td with text "Loudspeaker" ).
`[*[contains(.,'Loudspeaker')]]` check if this (second td) has a child with text Loudspeaker in any children.
`/../h:td[last()]/text()`  get the text of last td off parent.

But what you seem like to do is something like:
`(//h:tr[h:td/*[contains(.,'Loudspeaker')]])` find all tr with has text "Loudspeaker" 
`[2]` select the second of this trs.
`/h:td[last()]/.`  text of any children of last td of this second  found tr.

Therefor try (not tested!):

```
(//h:tr[h:td/*[contains(.,'Loudspeaker')]])[2]/h:td[last()]/.
```

Comment: Tried this but no luck. Thanks. As mentioned in the above comment, (//h:td[1][*[contains(.,'Loudspeaker')]]/../h:td[last()]/h:a/text()) worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public string FindElementUsingOneTrTwoTd(string tblName, string className, string searchString)
    {
        return "//*[@id=\"" + tblName + "\"]/tbody/tr/td[contains(normalize-space(@class), \"" + className + "\") and contains(string(),\"" + searchString + "\")]/../td[2]";
    }
```